# MYSQL #1005 - Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cmnd` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `dienthoai` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`usn`,`cmnd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

This is the first table i've created in mysql, then i make a query to create my second table userinfo, below

```
create table userinfo(
    cmnd int(9) primary key not null,
        ngaycapcmnd date,
        noicap varchar(50) character set utf8,
        hoten varchar(50) character set utf8 not null,
        ngaysinh date not null,
        quequan varchar(50) character set utf8,
        diachi varchar(100) character set utf8 not null,
        email varchar(100) unique not null,
        constraint fk_userinfo_userinit foreign key (cmnd) references userinit(cmnd)
)
```

Then it says when i press OK: #1005 - Can't create table 'xbook.userinfo' (errno: 150).
I use the lastest xampp. Can you guys help me solve this

Comment: Same as this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936076/1005-cant-create-table-table-name-errno-150

Comment: @Spudley: Similar, but no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because you are referencing to a column which does not have a separate key, *although it is part of a compound key*.

Try  adding a `KEY` in it, eg

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinit` 
(
  ......
  KEY (cmnd),         -- <<=== HERE
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`usn`,`cmnd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f642)

Comment: Thank you for answering my case, but i think when i add syntax: PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`usn`,`cmnd`) then `cmnd` is autoset a key.

Table userinit being there is generated by using Export in mysql.

Comment: `cmnd` does not have a key. it will only have a key if it is compounded by the two columns `id` and `usn`.

Comment: While this may solve the immediate problem of creating the table, it's not good advice to reference a non-unique column.